# What widely-available cross-platform command line program can I use to render a string containing color emoji

Tags: command-line, image, emoji

I have a [program](https://github.com/llimllib/ytgif) which allows users to create gifs from youtube videos using `yt-dlp` and `ffmpeg`. Unfortunately, `ffmpeg` [does not support color emojis](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5777).

Here's what it looks like when you try:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1:57 -to 2:00 -copyts -i /tmp/ytgif_cache/video_httpswwwyoutubecomwatchvnrqxmQruto.webm -filter_complex '[0:v] fps=10, scale=640:-1, split [a][b], [a] palettegen [p], [b][p] paletteuse, drawtext=borderw=1:bordercolor=black:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-10:text= flames ' flames.gif
```

[image: "flames" with two tofu emoji]

### Imagemagick

Imagemagick, as compiled for my by homebrew, does no better on a static image:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 72 "label:Hot  stuff" png:- | imgcat
```

gives:

[image: "hot stuff" with a tofu for the emoji]

(Possibly re-compiling with pango would fix this? But my users are not likely to want to have to install custom versions of imagemagick)

### Looking for suggestions

What are my other options? How can I render a text string containing emojis into an image suitable for a video caption in a reasonably cross-platform manner?

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) does support some emojis at the very least. You have to change the coder though. An example with [pango coder](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango):

```
magick -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 72 "pango:Hot  stuff
" test.png
```

Output:

[image: Text output]

I had no luck with the pepper () one though, on Windows latest version. Not entirely sure why, as its Unicode neighbors () and () did work fine. Perhaps a font issue. Or Unicode 7+ characters aren't supported too well within the not too up-to-date Pango version included with ImageMagick.

Could have better chances on Linux, where Pango is coming from. Don't have time to further mess with that, personally.

Comment: I'm on mac, where homebrew unfortunately doesn't ship pango compiled in with imagemagick. I also should have specified that I'd like to have color emoji support! Will edit the question.

Comment: Your question is wrong in that case, as it asks for cross-platform solution, not a Mac solution specifically. There are some potential solutions for Pango on Mac BTW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838714/error-when-trying-to-use-pango-with-imagemagick-on-osx https://east.fm/posts/imagemagick-pango/index.html

Comment: I'm on a mac but I am indeed looking for a cross-platform solution